Problems with logging into CrowPi2 Laptop (possible raspberry pi error)
Whenever booting up my crowpi2 laptop, i am faced with a shutdown/login screen. When I type the correct password in, it simply returns to that same screen.
I am not sure if it is my raspberry pi or my CrowPi2 OS (thought about re burning the OS image)
I have tried numerous times to log in, with nothing changing.
Accessing the terminal (ctrl + Alt + F1) will get me to the terminal, but it does not let me write anything as it keeps running the same lines of code over and over again.
ctrl-alt-F[2|3|4|5] did not work either

If you can afford $10 for an extra SD card it would be worthwhile to try that with a fresh image.

@goldilocks I can't just reburn it on the same sd card?

You could if you don't care about losing your stuff, although that won't rule out that the card is to blame -- you might not have the same problem, but some different one.

Ah gotcha, thank you!
